# How to switch from boolean to int in my Sudoku checker in Java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm creating A sodoku checker. This is what I've done so far but I've kind of hit a wall. In my checker I'm not allowed to change one of the method from int to a boolean, which is proving difficult for me.

```
public class SudokuVerifier {
public static int[][] candidateSolution()
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int [][] sudokuboard = new int [9][9];

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            sudokuboard[i][j] = input.nextInt();

    input.close();
    return sudokuboard;
}
public int verify(String candidateSolution)
//checking rows
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sudokuboard.length; i++ )
        if (validcheck(sudokuboard[i]))
            return 1;

}
/**
 * Tells the candidate to enter their sodoku puzzle
 * it then gets stored into a 2 dimensional array
 * array gets returned
 * tells them if it's right or wrong
 * @author sultan
 *
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
 int [][] sudokuboard = candidateSolution();
 System.out.print(solutionChecker(sudokuboard) ? "right solution" : "Wrong solution");

}
public static boolean solutionChecker(int [][] sudokuboard)
{

return true;
}

}
```

The "public int verify" is the part I can't change and it's giving me errors. So I'm wondering if there's a way from to keep this code more or less the same but using ints for my returns instead of boolean to calculate the rows, columns and 3X3 board.

Comment: So you want to use method that returns int instead of boolean, just make the method return 1 or 0 (true or false).

Comment: Or return the amount of fields that failed the validity check, with 0 meaning "no errors" == "solved".

Answer (score 0):

Just return int 1 meaning correct and 0 meaning incorrect. Assuming that `validcheck` returns true if the combination is correct:

```
public int verify(String candidateSolution)
//checking rows
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sudokuboard.length; i++ )
        if (! validcheck(sudokuboard[i]))
            return 0;

    return 1;

}
```

There are languages (like ANSI C) that don't use boolean at all. 0 means condition unfulfilled and anything other than 0 means condition fulfilled.

Comment: Thank you for the help. One more question, wondering if you could help me with this. For some reason my "sudokuboard" variable isn't working with my verify calculations even it's being used in my main method and it's working fine there. it's telling me "sudokuboard cannot be resolved into a variable" when i hover over it. Do you know why this is? The "sudokuboard" variable is = [9][9] for the columns and rows

Comment: Your `sudokuboard` variable is declared in the `main` method and it's not visible outside of it, so the `verify` method can't see that. You need to declare the variable outside the `main` method or pass it somehow from `main` to the `verify` method. It's really simple and I think you'll handle that. Good luck ;)

Comment: i did int [][] sudokuboard = new int [9][9]; and that seemed to have solved the issue but i'm not too sure if it's correct. I've been trying to do this sudoku checker thing for hours now, can you just help me out a little more and just tell me if that was right or not? really don't want to carry on for it to be wrong and mess up everything

Comment: There's not much to mess here, your code is really short. Where precisely do you need help? Currently your `solutionChecker` method is empty, your `verify` method isn't called anywhere in your code and we can't see the body of your `validcheck` method. There's still some stuff left to do and you're the best (and only) person to do that. So far your code looks pretty decent and I think you're on your way. If the specific problem shows up, then ask it here.

Answer (score 0):

Your function give only a value back when the if-Statement is true.
You need to add to give back a int when the statement is false.

Moritz